# How to use scikit-learn to predict the rate of change in a site's hit counts

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I want to predict the change in hit counts for a website using the rate of change. For example, if a site's hits double in a day (from 5,000 to 10,000), the rate of change is 2. If the hits go up by a half (5,000 to 7,500), then the rate of change is .5. Samples and rates of change will be calculated daily. I am fine with using raw hits instead of the rate of change, but that seems more difficult to work with.

I want to use scikit-learn to predict future rates of change. Given a set of past data points, how would I predict the future changes? Should I use a logistic regression? A support vector machine? Something else?

Thanks for your help! I'm new to scikit-learn, so feel free to comment if you need any more information about the problem.

Comment: What is your model on the hit counts? Any external factors? Or only the time series history to predict future evolution (which will decidedly *not* work wonders)?

Comment: Just a time series for now, but I plan to take other factors into account later on, such as social network shares and page activity. Is there anything you'd recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I forgot that you were looking for sklearn solution, but I think that simple weighted moving average could be good start. I usually try to start with something simple and only if that does not give me desired results go to more complicated stuff.

There are fancier approaches, but a simple one is to use weighted moving average, where you give more weight to most recent observations. For example:

```
import numpy as np

hits = np.array([100, 500, 300, 800, 900])

def predict(hits, weights):
    return np.average(hits[-len(weights) :], weights=weights)
```

Result:

```
>>> predict(hits, [0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
750.0
>>> 900 * 0.5 + 800 * 0.3 + 300 * 0.2
750.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! The solution doesn't necessarily have to be in scikit-learn, I just thought that it would give the best results. Is there anything you think that I should add or modify to improve the accuracy of the predictions, or will the weighted average be enough for now?

Comment: @cheese1756 One thing you could do is check for seasonality, for example, you might be getting significantly more hits every Friday. You can use auto-correlation function (ACF) to test for seasonality. And if you observe it, you should incorporate hits in last Friday, when predicting next Friday.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you, @Akavall. These suggestions are a really good way to start.